# Illegal mix of collations for simple stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, connector-j

I am attempting to run a stored procedure from Java using Connector/J on a MySQL server (5.5.23). The proc is

```
CREATE DEFINER = `[deleted]`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GETGROUP` 
( IN `uname` CHAR( 16 ) CHARSET latin1 ) NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA SQL 
SECURITY DEFINER SELECT `group` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = uname
```

However, it errors out with

```
java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) 
and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='"
```

I am using latin1_general_ci exclusively throughout my database, so I have no clue what's going on.

Comment: What is your connection character set?  Can you show the full code of your procedure?

Comment: Edited to show the full stored proc. character_set_connection is latin1.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the *collation* of your connection (you can force `uname` to use `latin1_general_ci` if you wish by adding `COLLATE latin1_general_ci` to the end of its declaration).

Comment: collation_connection is latin1_general_ci. I will try that.

Comment: How are you invoking the procedure?  Where does the argument come from?

Comment: The argument is a String that I specified. Still in the testing stages, so I know what the query should return. I'm invoking it via `getgroup = conn.prepareCall("{call getgroup(?)}");` and then `getgroup.setString(1, username);`, and finally `getgroup.executeQuery().getString(1);`

Comment: Do a 'show create table' on `user` and check that the collations of the table and fields match.

Comment: eggyal, adding `COLLATE latin1_general_ci` fixed the problem on this and all of the other stored procs. Put that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force `uname` to use `latin1_general_ci` if you wish by adding `COLLATE latin1_general_ci` to the end of its declaration.